# Return an Array of Arrays via PHP WSDL based web service

Tags: arrays, web-services, wsdl

I'm struggling with the following problem:

I have a PHP-based web service which needs to be consumed by various
clients. As long as I keep things simple, everything works fine. I figured that Axis2 and .NET don't like `soapenc:array` definitions in `WSDL`, so I created list types for mapping object arrays:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CourseList">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Courses" type="tns:Course" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now, if I include something like a List of `CourseLists` (using the same WSDL procedure), .NET fails as Axis2 (ADB) does with handling this data.
I checked the XML that comes over the wire with soapUI; it looks reasonable.

I'm really on the ropes with this one. Any hint would be highly appreciated.

TIA

```
 KB22
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is older than sin, but it's never been answered, and I struggled to find an answer myself when I recently ran into the same problem. There might be a better way to do this, but what I ultimately ended up doing was something like this.

This is actually even a level further, a 3-d array, but the general principle is the same.

```
<xs:element name="myOtherArray">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="someInsideArrayProperty" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

```
<xs:element name="myArray">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="someArrayProperty" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="yetAnotherArray" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ns:myOtherArray"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

```
<xs:element name="myResponse">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="myResponseArray" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="someProperty" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="someOtherProperty" type="xs:string"/>
                    ...
                    <xs:element name="anotherArray" type="ns:myArray" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```